# Better way to write a difference based date queries

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a review of existing code and have found the following SQL query which is used to get a selection of records last month.

Is there a more concise way of writing SQL to do what this date based clause does in MySQL?

```
SELECT foo
FROM some_table
WHERE some_date 
BETWEEN 
    DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) - INTERVAL 1 SECOND), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
AND 
    DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) - INTERVAL 1  SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

It works, but I just twitch a little every time I see it.
Can anyone else write it better?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `some_date` a string field?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (curdate seems like a more natural choice, but essentially, this looks fine to me)

Comment: @Uueerdo - it's a datetime field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to format the dates, they default to YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.

This is a little bit simpler:

```
SELECT foo 
FROM some_table
WHERE some_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND some_date < LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

So if `CURDATE()` is today, 2019-02-06, then:

- `- INTERVAL 2 MONTH` is 2018-12-06
- `LAST_DAY()` of that date is 2018-12-31
- `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` is 2019-01-01

Then the upper bound is:

- `- INTERVAL 1 MONTH` is 2019-1-06
- `LAST_DAY()` of that date is 2019-1-31
- `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` is 2019-02-01

The dates should be strictly less than 2019-02-01.

Using less than accounts for timestamps in the last second of the month, between 23:59:59.000 and 23:59:59.999.

Comment: Thanks Bill. It's been a while. I hope you're keeping well. Exactly what i was after.